# Where to place business-logic classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For example, I have a class which collect data from web-sites and return object collections.  This data doesn't store in the database so it is not model.  This class is used by many controllers so it is not controller.

Where can I place such files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should go into lib folder! As Modules perhaps!

Answer (score 2):

I would put them in app/models.  Then you don't have to deal with the autoload path or with require vs. require_dependency.

Just because a class isn't persisted to your database doesn't mean it isn't part of your data model.  Putting them in lib suggests they're some sort of utility class that doesn't have much to do with your app.

Rails confuses model and persistence.  I think it's fine to have some of your business logic along with your persistent entities, but there's no reason why you can't have model logic outside of your ActiveRecord objects.

Answer (score 0):

I usually  place those classes in the lib directory. and than just require them.

Comment: You would want to use require_dependency.  Otherwise you would have to restart the server to pick up changes.

Answer (score 0):

Its a **value object** and should remain same for whole site, and your controller or other components should use its refernce from model, class refernce should be in model and class it self can be put with value object